# streaming a remote image to the buffer using Koa

Tags: node.js, image, stream, buffer, koa

First time playing around with nodejs streams.. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here about how streams work.  When I make the request to the URL it logs out a 404.  If I try to write to the buffer it throws an error.
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object`

```
  1 const Koa = require('koa')
  2 const app = new Koa()
  3 const fs = require('fs')
  4 
  5 const url = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-cDeYCsNL-ZQ/UozsUJ7EqfI/AAAAAAAAGSk/EtuzOVpHoS0/s400/andy.png'
  6 app.use(ctx => {
  7   const buffer = new Buffer.alloc(1000)
  8   ctx.request.get(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(buffer))
  9   console.log(ctx.request)
 10   console.log(ctx.response)
 11 })
 12 
 13 app.listen(1337)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this part: `fs.createWriteStream(buffer)`. That method expects a string that contains a filesystem path, e.g. `fs.createWriteStream("image.png")`.

On a general level, your usecase doesn't require explicitly creating any Buffers. Even Koa is redundant. If you'd like to stream contents of an URL to hard disk using Buffers behind the scenes. You can write:

```
const request = require("request")
const fs = require("fs")

const url = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-cDeYCsNL-ZQ/UozsUJ7EqfI/AAAAAAAAGSk/EtuzOVpHoS0/s400/andy.png'

request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.png'))
```